# Pandas: Difference between dot and []

Tags: python, pandas

I thought with `pandas` [] and dot have the same `meaning` and can be used either or. However, that's not the case. Can you tell me the difference?

```
def load_event_data():
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=['created', 'total_gross'])
    df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created)
    return df.set_index('created').resample('D').sum().fillna(0)

event_data = load_event_data()
```

This here works:

```
event_data['something']= event_data['total_gross']
y = event_data['something']
```

This here works:

```
event_data.something = event_data['total_gross']
y = event_data.something
```

This here doesn't:

```
event_data['something']= event_data['total_gross']
y = event_data.something
```

Comment: they both work.